# Como usar una fuente externa para escribir un correo

Tags: html, css, web, formularios

Estoy escribiendo un correo `html` pero resulta ser que no se puede insertar mas si no el cuerpo no puedo especificar las cabeceras, usar etiquetas `<style>` ni conectar un archivo `css` externo

Ahora:

Como uso otras fuentes que no sean las genéricas intenté con esto:

```
@import
```

`<p style="@import url('https5//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=slabo+27px');font-family: Slabo;">HOLA</p>`

también intenté

`<p style="@font-face {
    font-family:Slabo;
    src: url('https5//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=slabo+27px');
}font-family: Slabo;">HOLA</p>`

Ahora ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes usar `<style>` (con import) o usar un CSS externo? Son los métodos más comunes para añadir fuentes externas en emails

Comment: tampoco funciona

Comment: ¿Cómo no funciona? ¿Qué es lo que intentaste? Y, por curiosidad, ¿esta pregunta está relacionada con la otra que has hecho antes sobre Acuity Scheduling?

Comment: si ninguna de las 2 funciona

Comment: ¿Has probado con link?

Comment: si no funciona el editor de código lo elimina

Comment: Si el problema es el mismo que en la otra pregunta, deberías editar la original para añadir esta información y cerrar ésta como duplicado.